# Products of fourier coefficients of distinct eigenforms.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_f(n)q^n$ and $g(z)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}b_g(m)q^m$ be two distinct eigenforms in $S(k,N)$, the space of holomorphic cusp forms of weight $k$ and level $N$. Can something be said about the product $$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{M}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M}a_f(n)b_g(m)$$ when $M$ is finite or $M= \infty$? If not a general result, is there a result for specific cases, e.g. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M}a_f(n)b_g(n)$ or for the case where N=1?

Comment: I am puzzled by your "e.g." in the last paragraph. The first sum factors as the product of $\sum_{n=1}^M a_f(n)$ with the corresponding sum for $g$ and hence considering the product doesn't really bring in any interesting new phenomena. The last sum $\sum_{n =1}^M a_f(n) b_g(n)$ is much more interesting since it's closely related to the Rankin--Selberg L-function (you might like to google this).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Sure, I agree that the first sum is just a product of sums for $f$ and $g$. Let me take a step back. I am interested in seeing what can be said about the product of Hecke operators: $TrT_m TrT_n$. (Later, I would need to sum over $m,n$ in a finite range.) Applying the trace formula seemed to use sums of products of more complicated terms, so I tried to just write out the expansion using fourier coefficients and see what comes up. Two kinds of terms: $a_f(n)a_f(m)$ and $a_f(m)a_g(n)$ occur. The first kind is well known. Can anything be said about the second kind?